# How to get several objects by name?

Tags: javascript, three.js

It seems that objects name doesn't have do be unique, several objects of the scene can have the same...

If I want a list of these objects do I have to write a *getObject**s**ByName* method or is there a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your own scene walker by using [Object3D.traverse()](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D.traverse), such as

```
var list = [];
scene.traverse(function(obj){
   if (obj.name == 'name') list.push(obj);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten the traverse function